Border with a space for a label
so i am working on a project for my college and I saw a very cool border style that I would like to replicate in my project, but I am having difficulty getting it right. I am using JavaScript, CSS, and React in this project.
How i want
I tried this:
.input-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 22vh;
}

.form-control-sub {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4vh;
  padding: 13px 40px 11px 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 5px solid var(--cor-principal);
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 1.6vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--cor-secundaria);
  position: relative;
}

.form-control-sub.data {
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-top-style: dashed;
  border-image: fill;
}

.data_label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 10px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: var(--cor-secundaria);
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-weight: 800;
  z-index: 1;
}

.data_label.cadastro {
  left: 59.5%;
}

and i get this:
How it is

Add a screenshot what you want to achieve, So we can check your requirements and help you out. Only code ain't gonna work.

Your question seems to be incomplete. You might have intended to attach an image at the end of your question...

That's what fieldsets and associated legends are for. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset

just keep the top container box has a normal border.likeborder: 1px solid black.then place a box on the left-top side,set it`s position as absolute, also set its background color,make sure the left-top box can cover the boder.

I have created a codepen, just refer it for your desired ui.
Hope it helps


body {
  background-color: #2c3333;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
input {
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-container {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  background-color: #2c3333;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #829898;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 20px;
}
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="input-container">
      <label>Data Nasc.</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



Modify it according to your convenience.
